# Web portal tool

Tags: portal

My team is moving away from APEX 4.1 and the question was asked, which technology should we go with for developing our new web portal.

We currently have SharePoint and Cognos, but I wanted to see if you had any other recommendations.

Comment: What don't you like about the tools you are using? Are trying to improve maintenabiliy, scalability, turn around time, or ...?

Comment: We cannot use SharePoint Designer.  Cognos is only used for creating charts/reports not portals.  We are looking for options that are available.

Answer (score 0):

As far as  JSR-168/JSR-286 portals are available you have a bunch of options from the usual suspects:

- IBM - Web Sphere
- Oracle - WebCenter

Or you could go open source:

Liferay (my preference for 'off the shelf' portals, also has enterprise support)

And a whole host of open source ones here http://java-source.net/open-source/portals

But I guess you need to ask yourself if you really need a portal or do you just need a CMS or a custom web app with some back end integration.

Usually, the learning curve and heft of portals will easily overshadow any benefits they bring and an entire custom application can be built much quicker, will run much leaner, cheaper and more closely match your requirements.

You're going to need in house expertise to set it up and maintain it either way, so think about if you want to be paying for fairly expensive licencing as well.

If you're just trying to decide on a platform to build your own application on, then consider their feature sets, future and your teams skills and experience.

I have successfully built 'portals' in Java EE and asp.net MVC and have implemented liferay portals. My preference and recommendation today is to build what is needed with asp.net MVC.